# An example of a fixed point of a diffeomorphism which is not a hyperbolic point

Tags: dynamical-systems, diffeomorphism

> Find an example of a $C^1$ diffeomorphism with a non-hyperbolic fixed
> point which is an accumulation of other fixed points.

A fixed point which is not an hyperbolic point must satisfy that $$f^n(p)=1,$$ and for $C^1$, it must hence give that $$f'(p)=1.$$

Let is place a fix point at $x=\pi/2$, and let that give $f'(p)=1\implies f'(\pi/2)=1$. Such a function is $f'(x)=\sin{x}$. We integrate and obtain $f(x)=\cos{x}+C$.

But here we have a C, and I don't know how that affects the results, being undefined.

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: I suspect that you could easily prove that no matter what value of $C$ you choose, there are only finitely many solutions to the equation $\cos x + C = x$.

Comment: Thanks. Let me develop on your idea:  since $\cos x$ is bounded on $[-1,1]$, then $x+[-1,1]$ will give finitely many solutions for C. However, x can be infinitely small, then we will get infinitely many solutions?

Comment: It sounds like you are open to the use of [nonstandard real analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis) in which infinitely small real numbers are a thing. Nonetheless, I suspect that whatever sources you are using to study dynamical systems, they are assuming standard real analysis; this would be the usual implicit assumption. So, sticking to standard real analysis, the only "infinitely small" real number is $0$, and there's not going to be a solution to your problem down that road.

Comment: @LeeMosher So the example is not good, is there a better example? Thanks